# How to rearrange a string equation?

Tags: c++, string

I am required to develop a program to solve linear equations. The programs
reads first an integer *n* which is the number of equations.
Then the program reads *n* lines containing the equations.
For example, the input to the program is like:

```
3
2x1+3x2+4x3=16
1x1+2x2+1x3=8
3x1+1x2+2x3=13
```

Any operation should first convert every equation to
the proper form. The equation proper should have the following properties

1. Variables are ordered alphabetically from left to right:

   ```
   3x2+2x1+4x3=16
   ```

   Should be

   ```
   2x1+3x2+4x3=16
   ```
2. Any variable should appear only once:

   ```
   4x1+3x2-2x1+4x3=16
   ```

   Should be

   ```
   2x1+3x2+4x3=16
   ```
3. Only one constant term should appear in the equation and it should be
   on the right hand side:

   ```
   2x1+3x2+5+4x3-11=10
   ```

   Should be

   ```
   2x1+3x2+4x3=16
   ```
4. Coefficient when equals to one or -1 the digit 1 is optional:

   ```
   1x1+3x2-1x3=10
   ```

   Can be input as be

   ```
   x1+3x2-x3=10
   ```

What I have done so far is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string eqn[100];
    //get eq from user
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> eqn[i];
    }

    size_t  s = 0;
    size_t  y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= ((eqn[i].length() - ((eqn[i].length() - 3) / 4)) / 3); x++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            ostringstream ss;
            ss << x;
            string j = ss.str();
            for (int t = 0; t < eqn[i].length(); t++) {
                y = eqn[t].find("x" + j, y + 1);
                if (y < eqn[i].length()) { counter++; }
            }
            for (int o = 1; o <= counter; o++) {
                s = eqn[i].find("x" + j, s + 1);
                string x1 = eqn[i].substr(s - 1, 3);
                string x2 = x2 + x1;
                cout << x1;


            }


        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int k;  cin >> k;

    return 0;
}
```

but things became over complicated, and I am not sure if that is the right approach..

Is there a better way to operate on a string equation other than `find()`, `substr()`?
How should I approach the problem?

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: it's a university project i am tasked with ,but i got stuck and don't know a better way to handle the problem.

Comment: Doing this with `find()`, `substr()` is probably possible but tedious. Making a grammar and writing a parser sounds easier (to me) but this could be a challenge also if you never heard about compiler construction or formal languages. I just recommended somebody else with similar issues to have a look at [Syntax Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram). If you managed to make such a syntax diagram it's probably not so hard to translate it into a handwritten parser with `if`s, `switch`s, and `for`-loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started with a [Syntax Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) to define (I wouldn't call it) a language:

[image: Syntax Diagram]

Then I translated this into a hand-written parser.

`parse-equation.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int parseDigit(const char *&la)
{
  switch (*la) {
    case '0': ++la; return 0;
    case '1': ++la; return 1;
    case '2': ++la; return 2;
    case '3': ++la; return 3;
    case '4': ++la; return 4;
    case '5': ++la; return 5;
    case '6': ++la; return 6;
    case '7': ++la; return 7;
    case '8': ++la; return 8;
    case '9': ++la; return 9;
    default: return -1; // ERROR!
  }
}

int parseNumber(const char *&la)
{
  int value = parseDigit(la);
  if (value < 0) return -1; // ERROR!
  for (;;) {
    const int digit = parseDigit(la);
    if (digit < 0) return value;
    value *= 10; value += digit;
  }
}

struct Term {
  int coeff; // -1 ... missing
  int expon; // -1 ... missing -> ERROR

  Term(int coeff = -1, int expon = 0): coeff(coeff), expon(expon) { }
};

Term parseTerm(const char *&la)
{
  Term term;
  term.coeff = parseNumber(la);
  if (*la == 'x') {
    ++la;
    term.expon = parseDigit(la);
    if (term.coeff < 0) term.coeff = 1; // tolerate missing coeff. for x
  }
  return term;
}

struct Expression {
  bool error;
  int coeffs[10];

  Expression(bool error = false): error(error)
  {
    std::fill(std::begin(coeffs), std::end(coeffs), 0);
  }
};

Expression parseExpression(const char *&la)
{
  Expression expr;
  int sign = +1;
  do {
    const Term term = parseTerm(la);
    if (term.expon < 0) return Expression(true); // ERROR!
    expr.coeffs[term.expon] += sign * term.coeff;
    switch (*la) {
      case '+': sign = +1; ++la; break;
      case '-': sign = -1; ++la; break;
      case '=': break;
      default: return Expression(true); // ERROR!
    }
  } while (*la != '=');
  ++la;
  // parse right hand side
  const int result = parseNumber(la);
  if (result < 0) return Expression(true); // ERROR!
  expr.coeffs[0] -= result;
  // check for extra chars
  switch (*la) {
    case '\n': ++la;
    case '\0': break;
    default: return Expression(true); // ERROR!
  }
  return expr;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Expression &expr)
{
  if (expr.error) out << "ERROR!";
  else {
    bool empty = true;
    for (size_t i = 9; i; --i) {
      const int coeff = expr.coeffs[i];
      if (coeff) out << coeff << 'x' << i << std::showpos, empty = false;
    }
    if (empty) out << 0;
    out << std::noshowpos << '=' << -expr.coeffs[0];
  }
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  const char *samples[] = {
    "2x1+3x2+4x3=16",
    "1x1+2x2+1x3=8",
    "3x1+1x2+2x3=13",
    "2x1+3x2+5+4x3-11=10",
    "x1+3x2-x3=10"
  };
  enum { nSamples = sizeof samples / sizeof *samples };
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nSamples; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Parse '" << samples[i] << "'\n";
    const char *la = samples[i];
    std::cout << "Got    " << parseExpression(la) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++` and tested in [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o parse-equation parse-equation.cc 

$ ./parse-equation
Parse '2x1+3x2+4x3=16'
Got    4x3+3x2+2x1=16
Parse '1x1+2x2+1x3=8'
Got    1x3+2x2+1x1=8
Parse '3x1+1x2+2x3=13'
Got    2x3+1x2+3x1=13
Parse '2x1+3x2+5+4x3-11=10'
Got    4x3+3x2+2x1=16
Parse 'x1+3x2-x3=10'
Got    -1x3+3x2+1x1=10

$
```

[**Life Demo on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2d05714af0afe66)

Note:

1. Instead of `parseDigit()` and `parseNumber()`, [`std::strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) could be used. This would reduce the code significantly.
2. I used `const char*` for the "read head" `la` (... abbr. for "look ahead"). The pure C++ way might have been a `std::stringstream` or a [`std::string::iterator`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1995109/7478597) but, may be, I'm not used enough to these new fancy things. For me, the `const char*` was the most intuitive way...
3. The result on right hand side is simply subtracted from the coefficient for x<sup>0</sup>. So, either the right hand side is 0, or the negative coefficient for x<sup>0</sup> becomes right hand side. For my pretty-printing `operator<<()`, I chose the latter option.
4. The error handling is rather poor and could be enhanced with more detailed infos about the reason of failed parsing. I left this out to not to "blow" the code even more.
5. The parser could be enhanced easily to skip white space at any appropriate place. This would improve the convenience.
6. In the current state, the result on right hand side might not be a negative number. I leave this extension as exercise.