# What's the point of iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Why should I use iterators?

For example if I have code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
   cout << vec[i];
```

what would be the advantage of writing

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it != vec.begin(); it != n.end(); ++it)
   cout << *it;
```

Also, why is writing `i < vec.size()` and `i++` more common in the first example and `it != begin()` and `++it` more common in the second example? What is the difference how you increment it and why not always use an equal sign?

I understand iterators can be useful in C++11 range-based for loops and some STD algorithms, but why should I do it in normal code, since it is more verbose?

Comment: This should cover it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178934/iterators-why-use-them

Comment: what if vec is a list?

Comment: Neither is as good as `std::for_each(begin(vec), end(vec), [](int x) { std::cout << x; });`.  Avoid off-by-one and other easy-to-inadvertently-make logic errors:  use algorithms and iterator ranges instead of hand-written loops.

Comment: @James McNellis Why is it better?

Comment: I've never seen anyone write this: `vector<int>::iterator it != vec.begin()`; I'm fairly sure that's a compile-time error.

Comment: "I understand iterators can be useful in C++11 range-based for loops and some STD algorithms, but why should I do it in normal code" - Why wouldn't range-Based for or algorithms not be considered normal code?

Answer (score 2):

Well not all containers have random access so you can do lookup on an index, so to normalize the interface iterators are fairly useful. Consider `std::list`. It doesn't support random access via a `[]` operator.

Taking this into account, to work across many heterogeneous types of containers, many STL functions like std::copy take iterators.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that iterators allow you to *iterate* over anything that supports iterators in a generic fashion.

As for it being more verbose, the extra verbosity isn't horrible (and your example could be slightly improved using `auto` or using the C++11 range-based for loop) but that's really a stylistic issue.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have this code:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> strings;

strings strs;
for( strings::const_iterator it = strs.begin(); it != strs.end(); ++it ) {
}
```

And later for watever reason we decide to switch to std::list. So we just replace typedef and code:

```
typedef std::list<std::string> strings;

strings strs;
for( strings::const_iterator it = strs.begin(); it != strs.end(); ++it ) {
}
```

Will work as before. But code with index variable will fail. Imagine what if you need to write a template code.

Answer (score 0):

The tl;dr is that iterators work better in a general case for different kinds of objects (when for example the size() method may be slow).

If you want to read more about it:

[Why use iterators instead of array indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices)

[Iterators.. why use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178934/iterators-why-use-them)